# What does the orange angle-bracket file/navigator icon in VS Code mean?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-mac, visual-studio-mac-2022

I haven't had any issues with using Visual Studio until now, I am on a Mac, but until recently now when I load the app my files will have this angle backet as a icon in the tab name and list name. no reason of this to be happen as far as im concerned. seems buggy
[image]

Comment: You seem to have a bunch of extensions installed - what does the middle list ("Animal DNA", "BASIC", etc) represent? Is "Pets" a file on-disk (if so, what's it's extension?) or something displayed by an extension?

Comment: Im a wiki editor for a game i play, i just copy the code into an editor to clean it up and organize. But the issue was when that icon appeared the environment was different it had red dot markers i could set and the color of text was different. I just made a new file and copyed it over instead and it went away hasn’t come back.

Answer (score 0):

This is just the icon for that language/extension the file has.

Comment: ah yes I was looking around and found out that the file somehow got change to html which is what that icon is for that language. once I changed it back to LUA everything was fine ... lol . thanks